# How to add Material You dynamic color to a SwipeRefreshLayout widget?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: swiperefresh]

I'm trying to change the default black color of the pull to refresh arrow to a Material You dynamic color (for instance, the user's primary color based on their wallpaper). It doesn't seem to be possible to do over XML, and I tried over Kotlin but it wasn't pulling the dynamic color. I know that for `SwipeRefreshLayout`, you have to use either `setColorSchemeColors()` or `setColorSchemeResources()`, but I can't seem to figure out how to pull the dynamic colors.

Answer (score 0):

```java
SmartRefreshLayout.setDefaultRefreshHeaderCreater((context, layout) -> {
    layout.setPrimaryColorsId(R.color.main_blue, android.R.color.white); 
    return new ClassicsHeader(context); 
});
```

Comment: This is not the answer